# Python - Faster way to load several images?

Tags: python, numpy

one of the tasks on my project is to load a dataset (chars74k) and set the label for each image. In this implementation, I already have a matrix with other images and a list with their respective labels. In order to do the task, I wrote the following code:

```
#images: (input/output)matrix of images
#labels: (input/output)list of labels
#path:   (input)path to my root folder of images. It is like this:
# path
#   |-folder1
#   |-folder2
#   |-folder3
#   |-...
#   |-lastFolder

def loadChars74k(images, labels, path):
    # list of directories
    dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item)) ]

    # for each subfolder, open all files, append to list of images x and set path as label in y
    for subfolder in dirlist:   
        imagePath = glob.glob(path + '/' + subfolder +'/*.Bmp')
        print "folder ", subfolder, " has ",len(imagePath), " images and matrix of images is:", images.shape, "labels are:", len(labels)
        for i in range(len(imagePath)):
            anImage = numpy.array(Image.open(imagePath[i]).convert('L'), 'f').ravel()
            images = numpy.vstack((images,anImage))
            labels.append(subfolder)
```

It works fine, but it is taking too long (around 20 minutes). I wonder if there is a faster way to load the images and set the labels.

Regards.

Comment: I'm guessing that the lion's share of processing time is on `Image.open(...)`. Do you really need to hold all that in memory? Maybe just hold a reference to the image path and read the file when necessary?

Comment: also, why are you doing `for i in range(len(imagePath)): ... imagePath[i]`? Don't loop over a list's indices just to then index that list: just loop over the list itself.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm looping and opening all images to load in a numpy.array and then appending the image to 'images'. What's wrong on this?

Comment: It's taking so long almost CERTAINLY because you're opening so many images. Do you need all the image data?

Comment: Yes, I'm training a neural network, so I need to load A LOT of images (at least 60k)

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you're surprised it's a lengthy operation...? It takes time to read from disk!

Comment: If the image size is constant, you should pre-allocate the correct sized array and write directly to the right location, saving costly calls to `vstack`.

Comment: Why not train your net on batches of images which you read from disk on the fly, rather than trying to load them  all into memory at the same time?

Comment: It's a good idea, but I think loading everything at once would be faster than load every time from disk

Comment: What makes you think that? Have you timed it?

Comment: I didn't but it makes sense, as I will load everytime the mini batch from the disk instead of loading from memory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research, I was able to improve the code in this way:

```
def loadChars74k(images, labels, path):
    # list of directories
    dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item)) ]

    # for each subfolder, open all files, append to list of images x and set path as label in y
    for subfolder in dirlist:   
        imagePath = glob.glob(path + '/' + subfolder +'/*.Bmp')
        im_array = numpy.array( [numpy.array(Image.open(imagePath[i]).convert('L'), 'f').ravel() for i in range(len(imagePath))] )
        images = numpy.vstack((images, im_array))
        for i in range(len(imagePath)):
            labels.append(subfolder)

    return images, labels
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible to improve even more, but it's ok for now! It's taking now 33 seconds!

Comment: How did this improve the speed?

Comment: LOL! This code is absolutely wrong! the image reading part is outside the loop.